# Return std::variant from a function

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, clang++, variant

I am trying to return either a `std::vector<long>` or `std::vector<char>` from my function but the compailer complains about this line `ret = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};`

```
class CharFactory {
    public:
        static std::vector<std::variant<long,char>> getChars(TokenType t){
            std::vector<std::variant<long,char>> ret;
            switch (t) {
                case TokenType::BINOP:
                    ret = {'+','-','*','/'};
                    break;
                case TokenType::NUMBER:
                    ret = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
                    break;
                case TokenType::LP:
                    ret = {'('};
                    break;
                case TokenType::RP:
                    ret = {')'};
                    break;
                default:
                    ret = {};
            }
            return ret;
        }
};
```

I use Xcode 11.2.1 with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12). The error message I am getting is

```
c.cpp:28:25: error: no viable overloaded '='
                    ret = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
```

I have done some googling but could not find a solution. How can I fix the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ret = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
```

This is ambiguous. You have a variant of `long` and `char`, but those are `int` literals. What should they be converted into? `long` and `char`?

If you want them to be `long`, put `long` literals instead:

```
ret = { 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 0L };
```

Comment: Thanks! I was expecting the compiler to interpret `int` as `long` in this case, but apparently I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this error happened in 2019. Now, `ret = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};` works with both clang and gcc. The `long` type is chosen in the variant.

https://godbolt.org/z/TY6Gxjjx6